# Error "cstddef: No such file or directory" on use AzureIoTHub

Tags: arduino-mega, iot

Good Morning
I'm trying to integrate with Azure IoT with Arduino Mega 2560.
I imported the AzureIoTHub and AzureIoTUtility lib.

I just created this part of the code

```
 #include <AzureIoTHub.h>

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

however, when I compile, I get the following error message.

> In file included from
> C:\Users\MercurioNote\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AzureIoTUtility\src/azure_c_shared_utility/platform.h:7:0,
> from C:\Users\MercurioNote\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AzureIoTUtility\src/AzureIoTUtility.h:7,
> from C:\Users\MercurioNote\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AzureIoTHub\src/AzureIoTHub.h:7,
> from D:\Documents\Dev\Pocos\Arduino\ArduinoSolution\ArduinoSolution.ino\WiFiPoco\RoboCore\azureHub\azureHub.ino:3:
> C:\Users\MercurioNote\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AzureIoTUtility\src/azure_c_shared_utility/strings.h:8:10:
> fatal error: cstddef: No such file or directory  #include

I imported ArduinoStl and the problem continued.

what am i doing wrong in this case?

thanks

Comment: Did you happen to read the (very short) list of supported hardware in the README of the Azure IoT library? It is only for ESP8266 and ESP32 (and then only specific ones by the look of it).

Answer (score 0):

Azure IoT is only supported on ESP8266 and ESP32. As stated in the [README](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-arduino/blob/master/README.md) for the library:

> Currently supported hardware:
>
> - ESP8266 based boards with [esp8266/arduino](https://github.com/esp8266/arduino)
>
>   - SparkFun [Thing](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13711)
>   - Adafruit [Feather Huzzah](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2821)
> - ESP32 based boards with [espressif/arduino-esp32](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32)
>
>   - Adafruit [HUZZAH32](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3405)